# BMP to GIF in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gif, bmp

**Matlab Version : 7.8.0**

I am reading a bmp file in matlab by using *imread* function -

```
i = imread('lena.bmp');
```

now i want to convert this *i* matrix into gif format. But since we don't have color map table, how could we do so.

is there a way to generate map vector from the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is using `rgb2ind`:

```
 [x,map]=rgb2ind(i,256);
 imwrite(x,map,'C:\test.gif');
```

I assumed that you want to use 256 colors in your color map. You can play with it to create more/less color quantization vs. file size.

Comment: Great! It was so straight and google gave me nothing. Thanks for your help. It solved my problem.